# How do i make the radio button beside label?

Tags: html, css

i want to make the radio button next to label but its stuck in the middle and is a big circle but it would always appear at the center and has a bigger size, the radio appears to be sitting on a whole line .. i think the problem is with the width but i tried separating the radio and it still doesnt work

```css
form {
  width: 60vw;
  max-width: 500px;
  min-width: 300px;
  margin: auto;
  padding-bottom: 2em;
  background-color: #1b1b32;
  padding-left: 25px;
  padding-right: 25px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  margin-top: 15px;
}

input,
textarea,
select {
  margin: 10px 0 0 0;
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 2em;
  border-radius: 5px;
  border: none;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  margin-top: 5px;
  padding: 5px;
}

fieldset {
  border: none;
  padding: 2rem 0;
}
```

```html
     <p>Would you recommend this to your friend?</p>  
    </fieldset>
    <fieldset>      
      <label><input type="radio"/>Yes</label>
    </fieldset>
  </form>

</body>
```

Comment: this is the image :https://drive.google.com/file/d/1esyRSkvx1q3LUUVH_YuF23FCL37DzQwY/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Please edit your post and click the image tag to attach the image.  The link is pointless because it wants me to log in !!!!

Answer (score 0):

Honestly, a little bit of effort on your part googling will help you a lot

```html
<label for='inp'>Yes</label><input id='inp' type="radio"/><br>
<input id='inp1' type="radio"/><label for='inp1'>Yes</label>
```

Comment: Thankyou but nothing happens, it still the same as https://drive.google.com/file/d/1esyRSkvx1q3LUUVH_YuF23FCL37DzQwY/view but i managed to fix it like this https://drive.google.com/file/d/1oEniNUhsRo5YpmTWJDa3QPka0drRcMFd/view

Comment: well of course nothing happens.  what did you expect?  You asked how to place the label next to the radio button.  The solution does that.  If you want it to do something you have to tell us what you want it to do